# How can I use jQuery to follow the cursor with a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div in the shape of a circle that follows your mouse using Javascript, but I want it to stop when it hits the edge of a container div. How would I do that? Here is the Javascript im using:

```
var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
mouseX = e.pageX;
mouseY = e.pageY;
});

// cache the selector
var follower = $("#follower");
var xp = 0, yp = 0;
var loop = setInterval(function(){
// change 12 to alter damping higher is slower
xp += (mouseX - xp) / 12;
yp += (mouseY - yp) / 12;
follower.css({left:xp, top:yp});

}, 30);
```

and here is everything else I have so far: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t_man/JUknN/9/)

Please help, and thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to establish the limits of the element that moves...

```
var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0, limitX = 150-15, limitY = 150-15;
$(window).mousemove(function(e){
   mouseX = Math.min(e.pageX, limitX);
   mouseY = Math.min(e.pageY, limitY);
});
```

Where `150` is the width/height of your container, and `15` is the size of your cursor

http://jsfiddle.net/fhmkf/